# Powershell: Combine next line with current line

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I am looking for desired output as shown below. The main concept is to join the next line with current line and result into one line if it ends with a character.

Thank you

[image: Current Output]
[image: Desired Output]

```
$file = 'textfile.txt'
$reportObject = @() 

foreach ($line in $file) {

  $content = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file)

  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $content.count; $i++) {

    $line = $content[$i]

    if ($line.StartsWith("Users")) {

      $a = 0

      while ($content[$i + $a].EndsWith("\")) {                                                #"

        $reportObject += $content[$i + $a]

        $a++

      }

      $reportObject += $content[$i + $a]

    }

  }
  $reportObject
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading the entire file repeatedly for every line?

Comment: Do you have a better way? Please share. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# Use
#   $reportObject = (Get-Content ...
# to assign the resulting array of lines to your variable.
(Get-Content -Raw textfile.txt) -replace '\\\r?\n' -split '\r?\n'
```

- `Get-Content -Raw textfile.txt` reads the entire file into a single, multi-line strings, due to use of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch.
- `-replace '\\\r?\n'` replaces a `\` char. (escape as `\\`) followed by a newline (`\r?\n`)<sup>[1]</sup> with the (implied) empty string, and therefore effectively *removes* the matched sequence.

  - For more information about the regex-based `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).
- `-split '\r?\n'` splits the resulting string back into an array of individual lines.

  - For more information about the regex-based `-split` operator, see [`about_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split).

**Note**: If the input file had a trailing newline, the above array will have an additional *empty* element at the end:

- If there are no *other* empty lines in the input (that you need to preserve), you can simply append `-ne ''` to the command above to remove all empty-string elements.
- To only remove the *last* element, the simplest (albeit not most efficient) solution is to append
  `| Select-Object -SkipLast 1` - see [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s documentation.

---

<sup>[1] This regex is a cross-platform way of matching a newline: it matches both Windows-style CRLF sequences (`\r\n`) and Unix-style LF-only (`\n`) newlines.</sup>